# Scroll animation in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a sticky header that is initially transparent, then on scroll becomes white. I am using this code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 100) {
        $(".sticky").addClass("color");
    } else {
        $(".sticky").removeClass("color");
    }
});
```

and it works well. The only problem is, if you load the page and your in the middle of the page - the animation isn't activated. It's in its original state of a transparent background.

Is there a way I can alter this so that it always works if you are 100px down the page, regardless of where the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add same function in document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 100) {
        $(".sticky").addClass("color");
    } else {
        $(".sticky").removeClass("color");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try below js.
and also see result that you want in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/634d6vgq/211/
by reloading the frame of output part

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $(".stickey").addClass("color");
    } else {
        //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
       $(".stickey").removeClass("color");
    }
});
```

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0}

html {
    background: lightgray;
    height: 5000px;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    height: auto;
    background-color:transparent;  
    
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.header.color {
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header stickey">the header</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve the problem if you store the value so you can restore it whenever needed. (not tested)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('scrollValue') === null)
    {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        sessionStorage.setItem('scrollValue', scroll);
    }
    else
    {
        var scroll = sessionStorage.getItem('scrollValue');
    }

    if (scroll >= 100) {
        $(".sticky").addClass("color");
    } else {
        $(".sticky").removeClass("color");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
  $('header').addClass('newclass');
 } else {
  $('header').removeClass('newclass');
 }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* background-color: #FFE4C4; */
  min-height:1000px;
}
/*----------This css for Header Navigation Bars-----------*/
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  /* min-height:700px; */
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  /* background-color:skyblue; */
  background: rgba(211, 84, 0, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.containerNav {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 500px;
}
#logo {
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
  font-family: Calibri;
}
nav {
  float: right;
}
nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Calibri;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
}
header.newclass {
  /* background:rgba(211,84,0,0.9); */
  background-color: #DC143C;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
header.newclass #logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
header.newclass nav a {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="containerNav">
      <div id="logo">Header</div>
      <nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a> 
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="Blog.html">Blog</a>
        <a href="#">Friends</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```